# More efficient way to re-assign or convert values?

Tags: r

I have columns in R that looks similar to the one shown here:

```
Values     Type
----------------
  5.44     Good
 10.31     Bad
 25.09     Good
  4.22     Bad
```

I want to convert the 'Bad' values to negative, while keeping the 'Good' remain the same.

The end result looks like this:

```
Values   Type
--------------
  5.44   Good
-10.31   Bad
 25.09   Good
 -4.22   Bad
```

To achieve this, I've been doing this so far.

```
df$Values[df$Type=="Bad"] <- df$Values[df$Type=="Bad"]*(-1)
```

I was wondering if there was a better/more intuitive/more efficient way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems quite efficient and intuitive to me... 

Answer (score 1):

You could replace on a subset which is faster than `ifelse` (which is actually what you're doing):

```
rp <- dat$Type == 'Bad'
dat$Values[rp] <- -dat$Values[rp]
dat
#   Values Type
# 1   5.44 Good
# 2 -10.31  Bad
# 3  25.09 Good
# 4  -4.22  Bad
```

**Microbenchmark:**

```
dat <- dat[sample(nrow(dat), 1e6, replace=T), ]

> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   ifelse=dat$Values <- ifelse(dat$Type == 'Bad', -dat$Values, dat$Values),
+   repl={
+     rp <- dat$Type == 'Bad'
+     dat$Values[rp] <- -dat$Values[rp]
+   }, 
+   repl2={
+     rp <- dat$Type == 'Bad'
+     dat$Values[rp] <- dat$Values[rp]*(-1)
+   }, 
+   times=100
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval cld
 ifelse 41.82709 70.56517 91.43609 74.06420 102.21062 265.3104   100   b
   repl 21.93701 22.46768 38.71844 23.74447  50.53454 142.1708   100  a 
  repl2 21.91698 22.90829 41.39714 27.58037  51.81883 143.1500   100  a
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Values = c(5.44, 10.31, 25.09, 4.22), Type = c("Good", 
"Bad", "Good", "Bad")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Type=='Bad', Values:=-Values]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(Values = if_else(Type=="Bad", (-1)*Values, Values)))
```

Comment: Error: unexpected '='

Answer (score 0):

Many people find `mutate` from `dplyr` more intuitive.

The code below basically reads:

1. Take `df`
2. Change the column `Values` according to the following condition:
3. If in a given row `Type` is "Bad", change the value.
4. Otherwise, keep the same value.
5. Assign this to `df` so you replace the old dataset.

```r
df <- df |> dplyr::mutate(Values = ifelse(Type == "Bad", Values*(-1), Values))
```

Comment: I get Error: unexpected '='

Answer (score 0):

```r
df$Values=ifelse(df$Type=="Bad",df$Values * -1, df$Values)
```